Getting error as no element found for iframe

   (scroll
   
   • 
   
      Y
      •#document (https://vm-97e9e0bf-03bb-4380-a49e-912ae79dd9c9-8000. in=
      vmprovider.projects.hrcdn.net/test.html)
      •
      
         (scroll)
         v 
         
            ‹meta charset="utf-8">
            ‹meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
            Drag and Drop
            • 
            
               #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left;
               margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; background-color: aquamarine } #droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left;
               margin: 10px; background-color:#CDDC39 } 
            
            script src="https://code.jguery.com/jguery-1.12.4.js"> ‹script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jguery-ui.js">
            • ‹script>
            $( function() {
            $( "#draggable" ) .draggable();
            $( "#droppable" ). droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
            -addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
            •find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
            // var inputval=document.getElementById("dataEntry").value
            //download (inputval,
            "dummyText.txt",
            "text/plain");
            $("#dropStatus") .append ("Yay, you dropped it")
            html
            body
            });
            }):
            
         
         * 
         
            • 
            @
            •
            
               
                  Drag me to my target
               
               
                  == $0
                  Drop here
Written code to locate iframe:
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='./test.html']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
URL: https://vm-97e9e0bf-03bb-4380-a49e-912ae79dd9c9-8000.in-vmprovider.projects.hrcdn.net/

HTML
Html Code:
 (scroll)



*#document (https://vm-b64ffe1f-0570-43cb-a965-ec72e589b141-8000. in-
Don't post relevant information in comments. Instead, edit your post and add it there, properly formatted. Also, format the code in your post as code. If you don't know how to do that, take a look at the provided help.

Also, you need to post the relevant HTML. It's likely that your locator is either wrong or there's something else going on in the page like another IFRAME, etc. We can't help without the additional info. The URL to the page would help solve the problem faster.

here is the url on which i need to perform drag and drop operation:
https://vm-b64ffe1f-0570-43cb-a965-ec72e589b141-8000.in-vmprovider.projects.hrcdn.net/
